# How can version changes to my documents without creating separate files?

Tags: version-control, versioning

A while ago, I was writing some code, but accidentally deleted some good code while I was deleting bad code. From then on I started creating versions of my files, I would name each file with the date and a version number.

However, this is a pain in the ass, having to give a unique name to each file and then going to my core file and changing the reference to the name of the new file.

And then, just the other day, I accidentally overwrote something important even with this method, probably because of a typo in naming.

Needless to say, this method sucks.

I'm looking for suggestions on better practices, better tools. I've been looking at version control, but a lot of them, Git SVN look really complicated. The idea is to speed up the whole versioning process, not make it harder by having to do command line.

Right now, I'm hoping that there's a tool that would save a unique version of the file every time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, and give me one button to create a finalized version.

Comment: mentioning what platform(s) you work on could help us recommend tools

Comment: I'm on windows, and write now I write mostly in Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two approaches to this problem:

1. **Versioning on demand**. This is the model used by *subversion, CVS*, etc., etc. When you have made a 'significant' change, you decide to tell the system "keep this version".
2. **Automatic versioning**. This is the model used by some old *VAXen, Eclipse, IDEA*, every *wiki* ever, and a few writer's tools. Every time you save, a new version is implicitly created. At some remove, old versions may be culled (e.g., only one version is kept from work performed a week ago, rather than every save).

It sounds like you would prefer #2, because it is "fool-proof" -- you never have to go, "oops, I should have 'checked in' / 'kept' my work before making this change." You can always roll back. One downside is that you have to manually step through the old versions to find something, because unlike with #1 you generally are not giving a description of each change.

Another downside is that for large files, or ones that are not easily diff'd/patched (i.e. binary files), you will start burning through disk space pretty fast..

As an aside, it sounds like you don't need 90% of the features in a standard SCM system -- branching, labeling, etc. -- but you might find uses for them eventually. So learning one may be a win in the long run. You can do this with svn, etc. but it will take some customizing. If you use a scriptable editor (emacs, vi, TextMate, whatever) you could redefine the "Save" command as "Save and make a new version".

Answer (score 13):

Subversion is more or less the gold standard.

I'd suggest (especially for a newbie) that you check out BeanStalk (www.Beanstalkapp.com) to run your subversion server and TortoiseSVN for your client.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 While there are lots of good versioning systems, Subversion has a  good graphic and command line tools and helpers which will be a good resource for anyone starting out with version control.

Comment: VisualSVN server is free and easy to setup and TortoiseSVN is a great client. Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue with SVN is that there seems to be an extra step. The check in. Right now I'm having a hard time renaming files. I suspect that checking in after every save will  be similarly frustrating.

Comment: Subversion *was* the gold standard (no qualifiers), having beaten CVS and VSS.  Now it only remains the gold standard in *some* communities.  Others have migrated more or less completely to Git.  Those communities would say that Git is "more or less the gold standard."  :)

Comment: Neil - I think you might be missing the big picture a bit with respect to Version Management.  First, version management really works in terms of snapshots of your entire project.  That is, you won't save every file individually (it'd be a nightmare).  Instead, you do a batch of work and then save the entire project directory off to SVN (only the differences are actually kept).  This ensures that you always have a consistent snapshot in time of your entire project.  This doesn't prevent you from restoring a single file by any means and I've done that more than once.

Second...(continued)

Comment: Second, version management isn't like a journaling file system or database: it isn't typical practice to save every change to every  file every time! In my case, I work through a batch of issue reports and then do a commit on the project.  Commits are almost always done on a daily basis and sometimes twice a day. Also, if I'm worried about a risky change, I commit before starting so I'm free to experiment. I know you don't want to lose *anything* but the effort required to save *everything* will cost far more in a typical year than you'll ever lose if you do daily commits in SVN.

Comment: No, *git* is the gold standard.

Comment: @Mark: commits are done once or twice a day?  I'd say you're not committing nearly often enough (but maybe you are, depending on the type of work).  You should commit every time a) you've completed a logically-related set of changes, or, if that is taking a very long time, b) it works without regressions.  The "related changeset" is very important for log purposes so you know what is going on.  Given typical types of work in my experience, you could be committing every 10 minutes, but never less often than every couple hours.

Comment: @mark I agree with rmeador--Code/test/commit/repeat.  Commit is virtually NO time required and trivial.  A single commit should have a single line of text describing the one change you made.  This is in my fantasy world anyway, in the real world I often end up not living up to my own ideals, but I've never regretted checking in too often.

Comment: I commit around 1-4 times per *hour* - always when the tests for some small new piece of functionality pass. My IDE (IDEA) I have configured to save all files (and as such to create a local history entry) after being idle for 5 seconds - a bit shorter than the time it takes for me to think about how to write the next line.

Comment: Wow, I though I was pretty hardcore but you guys (Bill, meador and Esko) have me beat by a mile.  I guess I look at the SVN repository as a place where my code goes to be safe rather than a continuous record of every change I've made.  Of course, I write pristine code continuously with nary a mistake so I never have to worry about backing anything out /wink.  Seriously, I'll generally finish one medium item or 3-4 small items between commits (large items, of course, can potentially be a part of dozens of commits). Anyway...works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Whatever you do, if someone mentions Visual SourceSafe -- run as fast as you can. VSS was created by Satan himself and handed down to torment developers the world over.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're in a position where you have to get a little bit out of your comfort zone and take some time to learn git. It's pretty easy to learn and use.

Believe me, it's really worth it. Time spent learning git is time well spent.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not working in a team, you could use something like Eclipse's local history feature. It stores versions of your files locally, and you can revert to previous versions whenever you feel like it. More details here: http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp (Search for "local history"). I am pretty sure other IDEs have such a feature too.

If you are collaborating with others on your code, there probably is no way around learning one of the standard tools like SVN, CVS or git. For most of them, there are plugins for many IDEs available, so you don't *have* to use the command line.

Comment: Even for local personal development, use a real Source Control system. It's just nicer and getting familiar with it is always a good thing.

Comment: How is it "nicer"? You have to setup a repository, commit explicitly, etc. There is much more overhead in using a proper source control system. I agree that learning how to use a source control system is definitely worth it, but since the OP is new to programming, something like local history is completely sufficient. I remember how frustrating I found CVS the first time I used it.

Comment: Great suggestion, though if I use eclipse I'll miss dreamweaver's auto complete.

Comment: rodion: I think your experience with CVS is a bit out of date. CVS is a bit of a bear. Mercurial (or Git) are a lot easier to set up.

Comment: Paul: I rarely use CVS these days any more. I just wrote about my first encounter with CVS, which was some five years ago and rather unpleasant.

Answer (score 4):

I currently use Subversion, but my source control experience is limited.

I would however suggest reading the tutorial by Eric Sink.

http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html

Answer (score 3):

Its best to learn how to use an existing 'industry standard' versioning tool like Subversion.  Even if you're new to programming and version control, SVN isn't that hard to learn and will serve you well.  I personally use and recommend [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) for Windows.  Both are free and quite simple to use.

For a system that creates a revision on every save, perhaps you should look into a [Versioning File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system).

Answer (score 3):

I think TortoiseSVN would be a good Subversion client for you to try if you're in Windows.  It won't do what you're looking for with every-time-I-save-I-get-a-new-version--you'll have to manually "commit" versions to the repository.  When you do a commit, that creates a new version, essentially saving your progress at that point.  TortoiseSVN is pretty user-friendly, and it's a GUI, so you won't be working at the command line.  You'll be able to do things like right-click a file in Windows Explorer and choose Commit to save your progress.  Plus, TortoiseSVN is free and open source.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion is not really complicated.  If you are using Windows, TortiseSVN will help a lot, if you are using Eclipse, subclipse plug-in is awesome. (You probably should be using eclipse regardless :) )

Some of the others are a bit complicated, but you just have to know the pattern with eclipse.  Maybe you could "Try it out" with an open source project or some existing subversion server.

The cycle would be:

First you "Check out" a repository.  This fills up your specified directory with the contents from the repository.

If you are doing it from the command line--it's "svn co"--there is enough help there to figure out the rest.

Second you edit your files.  You don't have to lock them or anything.

if you add a new file, you use "svn add filename" as soon as you add it.  This won't actually change the repository until you commit your changes.

When a group of edits are done, you check them in with "svn ci" (also svn commit works).
This one has a SLIGHT twist that you'll always forget--every commit needs a comment.  You don't have to specify the files you are committing or anything, but you do need to be in the top level of your project (it will commit everything below your directory.

So the procedure here is, go to the "root" of your project tree and type:

svn ci -m "comment"

piece of cake.

Finally, IF someone else is checking stuff in things get SLIGHTLY stranger.  before you commit, you should "update" and get their changes.  "svn up" is all it takes, but it may warn  you that there were merges.  This only happens when both of you edited the same file, and 90% of the time, the merges will go okay.  the rest of the time, it will put little markers in your file telling you what you changed and what they changed.  The "up" command will tell you which files it did this to.  Go look at them and clean the file up before you check the file in.

Always test between "svn up" and "svn ci", you never know if their crappy changes busted your pristine code.

That's really it.  It's so easy from the CLI, that the graphics environments are hardly worth it (but subclipse is really nice if you are in eclipse anyway because it will visually show you modified files that need to be checked in).

If you ever forget, svn's command line help is extremely terse and useful, tells you JUST what you need to know, and has help on all the sub-commands and options.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an easy-to-set-up version control system for Windows, I highly recommend [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/), an easy-to-use [Mercurial](http://selenic.com/mercurial/) frontend for Windows. You don't have to worry about setting up and keeping track of a repository separate from your files, but you always can do so if you'd like to. Mercurial is a great tool because it can grow with your needs. It has all the usual features like easy merging, etc. and is quite a bit easier to wrap your head around than Git in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

I think Git is really easy to use especially when you use GitHub. They also provide lots of good guides to get up and running.

```
http://github.com
http://github.com/guides/home
```

Comment: Well github is out because of its open source requirement.

Comment: you don't need github at all. the repository is the local directory

Comment: I know you don't need GitHub to use Git, I was just saying that it makes things easier. As Mark Brittingham outlined how Beanstalk makes working with SVN easy GitHub makes working with Git easy. Also there is no open source "requirement" for GitHub, I have many private repositories hosted there.

Comment: I was replying more to Neil's comment :)

Answer (score 2):

I've used Git, SVN, CVS, and Perforce.  On both Windows and Unix environments.

My vote is definitely for SVN, as it's ease of use, and flexibility.  I prever to use command-line now, but at one time I was using TortoiseSVN for Windows, which we were able to get non-technical people to use without a hitch.

Use SVN.

Answer (score 2):

You're definitely on the right track with recognizing the need for version control, but sound unsure what that might mean to you and your work.  Once you learn the concepts behind version control systems, you will really come to appreciate them.

The concepts are simple:  a source code control system is a piece of software designed to help you store and manage your code.  How you get code into and out of it differ based on which system you choose:  one paradigm is that you deliberately "check out" a file, make your changes to it, test it and make sure it's good, then check it back in.  Another is that you simply save every change you make because disk space is dirt cheap, much cheaper than your time and effort spent to create the source in the first place.

Another important concept is the "baseline" or "label".  When your product is in a ready-to-ship state, you tell the source code control system to create a "label" and tag every current item your entire source code base with that label.  That way, when someone reports a bug in version 4.1 you can go to your system, request all the files with the "Version 4.1" label and get exactly the source code they're having a problem with.

Having a source control tool integrated with your development environment makes the whole process much easier than having to mess with command lines.  (Don't discount command line because of their complexity, they deliver elegant control to an experienced user, and you eventually will become an experienced user.)  But for now, I'd recommend a source code tool that can automate the process as much as possible.

Some things to consider:  are you now, or are you planning to share the development with another developer?  That might make a difference on how you want to set up a server.  If you're developing alone on your own box, you can set it all up locally, but that's probably not the best approach for a team.  (If you're unsure, git is very flexible in that arena.)  Are you going to be storing large multimedia files, or just source code?  Some source code systems are designed to efficiently store only text files, and will not handle movies, sounds or image files very well.

Something else to know is that most newer source control systems require some kind of "daemon" program running on the server (Subversion, git, Perforce, Microsoft Team Foundation Server) while the older, simpler systems just use the file system directly (Visual Source Safe, cvs) and don't require a server program.

If you don't want to learn much and your demands are low, the simpler solutions should suffice.  Microsoft's Visual Source Safe used to come with their visual studio products, and was a very simple to use tool.  It's not very robust, it's Microsoft-only, and it can't handle large files well, but it's very, very easy to set up and use.  If you don't want to spend money, Subversion and git are two stellar open source solutions, and there is a lot of documentation for both on the web.

If you like to spend money, Perforce is considered an excellent choice for professional development teams (and I believe they have a free single-developer version.)  If you really like to spend lots of money and want to make Bill Gates happy, Microsoft's Team Foundation Server is a complete software development lifecycle manager, is extremely easy to use in the Windows environment, and very powerful; but you'd probably want to devote an entire Windows server (plus SQL Server) instance to host it, and it will cost you several thousand dollars just on licenses.  Unfortunately it is not the right tool for a one-man shop, or if you have no Windows admin experience.

If you have the budget or the connections, bringing in an experienced software engineer to help you get things started might be the quickest path to success.  Otherwise, you'll have to do some more research to learn which systems best fit your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever VCS you use, if you choose versioning on demand instead of automatic versioning (to borrow terms from Alex's post), you will have to go through some ceremony to:
-create,
-rename,
-move,
-copy, or
-delete 
a file that is under source control.

When you create a new file, you have to Add it to source control before you Commit your changes to the repository.

When you rename, move, copy, or delete a file under source control, do so with your VCS client.  In TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit, the move and copy operations are done with a right-click-and-drag, whereas the rename and delete operations are available via a right-click.

As you can imagine, changing things like the name of a project can be quite the hassle, hence the case for automatic versioning.

Ordinary file edits and any changes to files *not* under source control, do not require you to tell your VCS client about them.

Finally, for one-man projects, I prefer git over SVN because SVN requires at least 2 copies of everything: a repository (the "master" copy of the files and history) and a working copy (the copy you do your work on).  With git, the repository and working copy are the same thing, which makes my experience simpler.

Answer (score 1):

We use [SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/), which has great integration with Visual Studio, and is free for a single user. Depending on what framework and languages you're using, though, [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is a great free solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please read these articles by Eric Sink. Eric sink runs a company that creates a Source Control system called Vault. He explains in a newbie friendly manner how to do source control, best practices etc:

[Introduction to Source Control](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html)

I found it invaluable when I first wanted to understand Source Control.

SourceGear Vault is FREE for a single user. It's interface is intuitive and integrates well with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just you, you might want to try Bazaar. It's distributed like Git (so it'll be nice for a single person--no server to deal with), but one of their main goals was to make it it much easier to use than Git.

Also, there is a handy gui tool that should make it amazingly easy to use called ToroiseBzr. http://bazaar-vcs.org/TortoiseBzr

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact such a tool. It is called [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Distrib.html#Distrib).

Just create yourself a "~/.emacs" file and put the following lines in it:

```
(setq kept-new-versions 5)
(setq kept-old-versions 5)
```

And then restart emacs.

This tells emacs to save your 5 oldest and 5 newest versions of that file. They will be kept in files named filename~n~ where "filename" is your file's normal name, and "n" is the backup number.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop your project alone (don't need ane server for collaboration) Mercurial might be you system of choice. I personally value one of its features: it only uses one place to save its information, it is the **.hg** directory in the root of your project. It doesn't put its data into every directory (like SVN). This way the archive and the project directory is easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Visual Source Safe, Perforce, and Subversion.  They were all fine, but I would have to say that the support and extensions for Subversion just seemed slightly better.  If you're planning on entering/staying in the software industry, you MUST know the fundamentals to source control, and I would highly recommend setting up one of the source control services.  Subversion would be my recommendation and is free as well.  It will be complicated at first, but you really should use a SVN client to add a GUI to increase utility and cut down on all the complication you're observing.

Answer (score 0):

I quick google of "dreamweaver svn" reveals that many people are working with Subversion in Dreamweaver. I'm a advocate of version control, and SVN in particular, so I would recommend you look into that :)

If you don't want to use a full on version control system (as noted above), you may be able to improve your lot by refining and automating the procedure you described originally. Depending on your comfort with the tools you should be able to put together a script in DreamWeaver itself or in Windows Scripting ( Powershell, VBA, Perl, etc ) that will at least make date-named copies of the folder you are working in every so often. This will keep you from having to do it and make sure there aren't any typo-related problems. Further down that path you can have your script put a copy of your work on a backup drive or remote server, and then you'd have a back up, too.

I'm afraid I don't know much about DreamWeaver, but if it has much scripting support built-in you may even be able to "hook" into the Save/ Auto-Save functions and have them do exactly what you want.

Hope this helps,
adricnet